# Form Not Showing When Click on Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form that is hidden by default. and when clicked on a link it will display the form. But my jquery/javascript logic seems to be missing something as the console display something momentary and it hides. I have used "return false" at the end of the function to prevent the page from loading again. I hope that's what is happening. Anyway, let me know what am I missing here. heres the link to the project http://pctechtips.org/apps/todo/
Thanks

```
   /*
     * Script main body
     */
     $(document).ready(function() { 
        //hide form when doc loads first time
        $("#submit-form").hide();

        //listener for show hide form functionality
         $("#add-todo").click(function() {
            console.log(formId);
            toggleForm();
            return false; //return false to prevent page reload
         });
     });

     //functionality for show / hide form
     function toggleForm() {
        console.log(this+" clicked");
        if($("#submit-form").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#submit-form").show("slow", function() {
                console.log("form shown!");
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#submit-form").hide("slow", function() {
                console.log("form hidden!");
            });
        }   
     }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TodoList App</title>
    <!-- bootstrap, fontawsome cdn -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- local stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- jquery cdn -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- local javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/todo.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-drak bg-dark mb-4">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" aria-hidden="true"></i> Todo<strong>List</strong></a>
        </nav>
    <!-- /navbar -->
    <!-- todoList -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="add-item text-white text-center border col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 mb-4">
        <a id="add-todo" class="new-todo text-white text-center" href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enter new todo item</a>
        <div id="submit-form" class="form-hide add-item text-center col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
            <form class="">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Todo Title">        
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Todo Description">
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-12">Submit Todo</button>               
            </form>                 
        </div>
        <!-- horizontal line -->
            <hr>
        <!-- list items -->
        <h1 class="heading-4">Todo List Items</h1>
        <ul class="list-group mt-4 pb-4">
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            Cras justo odio
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            Dapibus ac facilisis in
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">2</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            Morbi leo risus
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            Morbi leo risus
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            Morbi leo risus
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is formid ? define formid. that might causing the problem

Comment: `console.log(formId);` fails (`formId` isn't defined), so the rest of the `click()` handler never runs -- and no `return false;` ever happens

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm posting the answer, but someone answered in the comment above. The problem was with a null variable being called through console.log(formId) and formId was not initialized or declare. Thanks